# Store data from text file into array

Tags: javascript

My text file has so many emails. I want to be read from the text and store into `emails = [];`.
But when I check my code, it only stores the last value from the text file.
This is my code :

```
var emails = [];
        jQuery.get('text.txt', function (data) {
            var lines = data.split("\n");
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
                emails.push(lines[i]);
            $('input[type="radio"].st13').each(function () {
                var radio = $(this);
                var email = $(this).parent().prev('td').html();
                console.log($.inArray(email, emails));
                if ($.inArray(email, emails) != -1) {
                    radio.prop('checked', true);
                }

            });
            }
        });
```

Please help me store all data in the text file into `email = [];` Like this:

```
emails = [
         'email@gg.com',
         'anna@domain.com'
       ];
```

Comment: Research JavaScript arrays in particular the push() method.

Comment: I'm not following this question... why the loop? `data.split("\n")` already gives you an array. You'll end up with the same result: https://jsfiddle.net/ntz6pr67/

Comment: thanks for your supports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array.push(item)`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp), like this:

```
for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
    emails.push(lines[i]);
}
```

If you use `emails = [lines[i]];`, then the `emails` array will be assigned with a new array `[lines[i]]` every time you loop. So the last iteration will be `emails = [lines[lastIndex]]`,
which is what you get after the loop ends.

Also, as someone noted:

> data.split("\n") already gives you an array.

which means you can add items to the array without the loop, like this:

```
emails = emails.concat(data.split("\n"));
```

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I was edited my code. I want auto check radio button when email got in text file. But my code only check radio on last value. I don't know why?

Comment: @Doublelift what is `console.log($.inArray(email, emails));` outputting to the console? are they all `-1` except the last one?

Comment: OK, I has fixed my problem. Thanks for your support